# Get the result console in text file java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to get the result of eclipse console in text file.
I tried this code but it didn't work...the file still empty

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/nadhmanovic/Bureau/output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

Any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get contents of your file because every time you call your code executed your file will get empty

To show fie contents you can use this

```
File f = new File("U:\\abc.txt");
Scanner in =new Scanner(f);
while(in.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

Comment: Also he shouldn't forget to close the stream or his file won't be saved properly.